# "TypeError: Input 'global_step' of 'ResourceApplyAdagradDA' Op has type int32 that does not match expected type of int64." What is this bug?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

While I was trying to use the AdaGradDual Optimizer, I got an error for the batch size I had entered. The batch size I entered was 300 because I have 60000 samples to train.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

start_time = time.time()



data = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot']

train_images = train_images/255.0

test_images = test_images/255.0

optimizer1 = tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(0.001,0)

model = keras.Sequential([
                           keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
                           keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="softsign"),
                           keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer1, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc1 = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print("Test acc is:", test_acc1)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    527                 as_ref=input_arg.is_ref,
--> 528                 preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
    529           except TypeError as err:

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1272           "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
-> 1273           (dtype.name, value.dtype.name, value))
   1274     return value

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype int32: <tf.Tensor 'training_16/AdagradDA/update_dense_22/kernel/Identity:0' shape=() dtype=int32>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-41ac628d29d8> in <module>()
     29 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer1, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
     30 
---> 31 model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
     32 
     33 test_loss, test_acc1 = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    725         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    726         workers=workers,
--> 727         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    728 
    729   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    673         validation_steps=validation_steps,
    674         validation_freq=validation_freq,
--> 675         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
    676 
    677   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    187   # function we recompile the metrics based on the updated
    188   # sample_weight_mode value.
--> 189   f = _make_execution_function(model, mode)
    190 
    191   # Prepare validation data. Hold references to the iterator and the input list

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in _make_execution_function(model, mode)
    564   if model._distribution_strategy:
    565     return distributed_training_utils._make_execution_function(model, mode)
--> 566   return model._make_execution_function(mode)
    567 
    568 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _make_execution_function(self, mode)
   2181   def _make_execution_function(self, mode):
   2182     if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
-> 2183       self._make_train_function()
   2184       return self.train_function
   2185     if mode == ModeKeys.TEST:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _make_train_function(self)
   2113           # Training updates
   2114           updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
-> 2115               params=self._collected_trainable_weights, loss=self.total_loss)
   2116           # Unconditional updates
   2117           updates += self.get_updates_for(None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizers.py in get_updates(self, loss, params)
    751       grads = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, params)
    752       opt_update = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
--> 753           grads, global_step=self.iterations)
    754 
    755     self.updates.append(opt_update)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/optimizer.py in apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, global_step, name)
    612           scope_name = var.op.name
    613         with ops.name_scope("update_" + scope_name), ops.colocate_with(var):
--> 614           update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
    615       if global_step is None:
    616         apply_updates = self._finish(update_ops, name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/optimizer.py in update_op(self, optimizer, g)
    169       return optimizer._resource_apply_sparse_duplicate_indices(
    170           g.values, self._v, g.indices)
--> 171     update_op = optimizer._resource_apply_dense(g, self._v)
    172     if self._v.constraint is not None:
    173       with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/adagrad_da.py in _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var)
    136         math_ops.cast(self._l2_regularization_strength, grad.dtype.base_dtype),
    137         global_step,
--> 138         use_locking=self._use_locking)
    139 
    140   def _apply_sparse(self, grad, var):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/gen_training_ops.py in resource_apply_adagrad_da(var, gradient_accumulator, gradient_squared_accumulator, grad, lr, l1, l2, global_step, use_locking, name)
   1351                                   grad=grad, lr=lr, l1=l1, l2=l2,
   1352                                   global_step=global_step,
-> 1353                                   use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
   1354   return _op
   1355   _result = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    549             if input_arg.type != types_pb2.DT_INVALID:
    550               raise TypeError("%s expected type of %s." %
--> 551                               (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
    552             else:
    553               # Update the maps with the default, if needed.

TypeError: Input 'global_step' of 'ResourceApplyAdagradDA' Op has type int32 that does not match expected type of int64.
```

I tried changing the values to 100, 30, 10, 0, and 1. None of those values worked and I got the same error. I am not sure what would fix this. I am using google colab and don't know how to exactly update the Tensorflow Version since a post mentioned the fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message:

```
TypeError: Input 'global_step' of 'ResourceApplyAdagradDA' Op has type int32 that does not match expected type of int64
```

It seems that the second parameter to the optimizer is expected to be int64. Since you are giving a Python integer it is converted to int32 by default. Try with this:

```
optimizer1 = tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradDAOptimizer(0.001, tf.constant(0, tf.int64))
```

I'm not sure if this is completely correct though, I think the training step might need to be a variable that you increment after each step. I think it should work like this, but maybe it will behave as if the optimizer was in the first step all the time.